# gcc -x java on debian stretch

Tags: java, linux, gcc, debian

The [Using the GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc.pdf) manual for `gcc` version 6.3.0 indicates support for the language option `-x java` on page 28 (page 42 of the pdf). Attempting this on debian stretch:

```
$ gcc -x java HelloWorld.java
gcc: error trying to exec 'ecj1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Installing what seems to be the required package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ecj1
Reading package lists... Done
...
Unpacking ecj1 (3.11.1-1) ...
Setting up ecj1 (3.11.1-1) ...
....
Reading state information... Done
```

However, I get the same error message when running `gcc` after this. In fact looking into `/usr/bin`, no executable `ecj1` has been installed, and running `apt-cache search ecj1` does not suggest any other package than the one I have installed.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-11) 6.3.0 20170321

$ uname -a
Linux right 4.8.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.5-1 (2016-10-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any suggestion as to what else I could try to get this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNU compiler for Java has to be installed:

```
$ apt-get install gcj-4.9 gcj-4-9-jdk
```

Use *apt-file* to search for packages containing *ecj1* as a file. Note that *apt-cache* only searches for package names/descriptions matching the search.

After the installation I was able to run it using

```
$ gcj-4-9 HelloWorld.java
```

instead of gcc.

Even though gcj is a front-end to gcc, gcc didn't work for me and was complaining about the classpath not being set. To get gcc working, it would probably require a different, more complex command.

If you're compiling a class that contains a main method, use the --main option.

```
$ gcj-4-9 --main=HelloWorld HelloWorld.java
```

Comment: Thank you very much Luc. Will remember to use `apt-file` going forward. On debian stretch, it looks like `gcj-6` is the package to install which gets rid of the missing `ecj1` error. I still have a missing classpath error when compiling HelloWorld.java but I ll figure it out.

Comment: @SvenWilliamson I got the same missing classpath error when using gcc. I managed to get it working using gcj itself. See the updated answer.

Comment: running `gcj-6` itself gives me a linking error (cannot find `-lgcj`) so I did `sudo apt-get install libgcj17-dev` but this did not eliminate the problem. Thanks your your help anyway :)

Comment: @SvenWilliamson did you notice I've added `gcj-4-9-jdk` to the list of packages to be installed?

Comment: oh yes sorry, there is no `4.9` version available on debian stretch, but installing both `gcj-6` and `gcj-6-jdk` brings me forward. Thank you. I am still getting an error though. Will edit my post.

Comment: I tried on debian jessie too (this time with `gcj-4.9` and `gcj-4.9-jdk`) and I get the same error as on debian stretch.

Comment: @SvenWilliamson Use the`--main=` option and define the class name containing a main method.

Comment: Perfect thank you !!! This works both for debian jessie and stretch. I am very grateful for your help.